# For Loop Inside Switch Statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement, nested-loops

I have certain ranges saved in array with price at index [3] and discount type at index [4] (%, fixed).
Anyone buying within those ranges should get available discount. 
My Current Problem is range of an array could be of any count, for example here in variable `$a`, there is `4 nested array`, but in certain case, i would be making `6 nested array`, or `8 nested array` , so on and so forth.

So, I was running for loop inside my switch statement, and i got an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'`.

Here is my code :-

```
<?php

$a = array(array('0', '10', '200', '0'), array('11', '20', '20', '1'), array('20', '50', '25', '1'), array('50', '100', '5000', '0'));

$quantity = 25;

$count = count($a);


switch($quantity) {
    for($i=0;$<=$count-1;$i++) {
        case ($quantity > $a[$i][0] && $quantity < $a[$i][1]) :
            echo "Discount Available for Quantity > ".$a[$i][0]." and < ".$a[$i][1];
            break;
    }
    default:
        echo 'No Discount';
        break;
}

?>
```

How should i design my algorithm for above scenario.

**NOTE**: Array Type :-

`$variable = array ("lowest_quantity_range", "highest_quantity_range", "discount_value", "discount_type");`

discount type will be either `1` for `%` or `0` for `fixed` amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you shouldn't even be using a switch at all here...

```
$a = array(
    array('0', '10', '200', '0'),
    array('11', '20', '20', '1'),
    array('20', '50', '25', '1'),
    array('50', '100', '5000', '0')
);

$quantity = 25;
$found = false;

foreach ($a as $item)
{
    if ($quantity >$item[0] && $quantity < $item[1])
    {
        echo "Discount Available for Quantity > ".$item[0]." and < ".$item[1];
        print_r($item);
        $found = true;
    }
}

if (!$found)
{
    echo "No Discounts";
}
```

Comment: What a Dumb! I am  :( Oh! seems like over caffeine. Thanks bro! Thanks a lot :) That was life saviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use for loop inside switch statement. You need to put the for loop outside the switch statement:

```
<?php

$a = array(array('0', '10', '200', '0'), array('11', '20', '20', '1'), array('20', '50', '25', '1'), array('50', '100', '5000', '0'));

$quantity = 25;

$count = count($a);

foreach($a as $item) {
switch($quantity) {

        case ($quantity >$item[0] && $quantity < $item[1]) :
            echo "Discount Available for Quantity > ".$item[0]." and < ".$item[1];
            break;
       default:
        echo 'No Discount';
        break;
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: And how would you handle default case ? won't there will be multiple default case too ?

Comment: You can actually create a $isDiscount flag before the switch, set it to false. When it goes to the discount condition set the flag to true. So after the foreach loop you can simply create an if condition of that flag to printout the 'No Discount' string if the flag is false.

Comment: And that didn't work , see here - http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/4mc-5y0 Run them.

main `http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4mc-5y0`

Comment: Thanks for your great tip, i got that working http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994159/2785554

Answer (score 0):

Example `for`-loop in a `switch` statement:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ "action" ] ) ) { 
    $action = $_POST[ "action" ];
    switch ( $action ) {
        case "add" : addItem(); break;
        case "del" : delItem(); break;
        case "undo" : for(
                            $i = 0; 
                            $i <= 10; 
                            $i ++ ) { 
                        switch ( $_SESSION[ "id" ] ) {
                            case $i : undoAction( $i ); break; 
                        }
                     }
                     $_SESSION = array();
                     break;
    }
}
```

I remember one script I did so I grabbed it for here. Make sure your `for`-loop starts after a `case` definition. In this example it's `"undo":` ...usually `for`-loops are packed in a `function` or method to make it more clean.
You cannot start a `for`-loop in place for a new `case` inside a `switch` statement.